# Java - Get LocalDateTime from Double

Tags: java, json, localdatetime

I am receiving this value in a Json format:

```
 {"time": 1643213994.7369497}
```

This time value is supposed to produce a DateTime value like this:

```
 2021-08-12T03:03:31.656050+00:00
```

How can I get this value parsed into a `LocalDateTime` object or the format above?

Comment: What does this represent?  It looks like [Epoch Time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time) and a fraction of a second.  Is that what it is?  Do you care about the milliseconds?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that number represents an Epoch Time, have you tried (in Java 8+) rounding it up and using

```
LocalDateTime myLocalDateTime = Instant.ofEpochMilli(yourTimeHere).atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toLocalDateTime();
```

for example?

You might want to replace `ZoneId.systemDefault()` with the `ZoneID` that is relevant to you.

Answer (score 0):

Since there's no timezone / offset information available in your source, you can convert it to an `Instant` and convert that to a `ZonedDateTime` or `OffsetDateTime` later.

A double like yours can be converted to an Instant using this method:

```java
    public static Instant toInstant(double value) {
        final long epochSecond = (long) Math.floor(value);
        final long nanoAdjustment = (long) ((value % 1.0) * 1000_000_000.0);

        return Instant.ofEpochSecond(epochSecond, nanoAdjustment);
    }
```

You can then later convert it to a `ZonedDateTime` like this:

```java
        Instant yourInstant = ...;
        ZonedDateTime zdt = yourInstant.atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault());
```